# Make border invisible with rowspan and colspan

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I know hiding a border is a common (and basic) question, but this is a (somewhat) unique case; try getting the border above the cell "WANT NO BORDER ABOVE THIS CELL" to disappear (**in Chrome**) while still using rowspans and colspans...

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        td {
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom-style:hidden; border-bottom-width:0px; border-bottom-color:white; border-bottom: 0;">2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td style="border-top-style:hidden; border-top-width:0px; border-top-color:white; border-top:0;">WANT NO BORDER ABOVE THIS CELL</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you're going to have to nest a div inside or explore `box-shadow: inset...` It looks like no matter what you do, you're stuck with the border from the first-item in that second `<tr>` tag taking over the whole row. (whatever you set fo cell 3 takes over the whole row.)

Comment: As mentioned, appear to be a bug in Chrome when border is set to collapse. Possible solution is to change to `<table style="border-spacing: 0">`

Comment: @Ason that does not work for me.

Comment: @keramat -- What does not work? ... do note, you'll remove the `border-collapse: collapse;` and use `border-spacing: 0` instead. With that the border will go away in Chrome/new Edge

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug in Google Chrome but here is an idea to have the visual you need using a pseudo element:

```css
td {
  border-style: solid;
}
.hide-border {
 position:relative;
}
.hide-border:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:-3px;
  height:3px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:#fff;
}
```

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="hide-border">WANT NO BORDER ABOVE THIS CELL</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: As this bug only appear when border collapse, one can simply swap the `<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">` with `<table style="border-spacing: 0">` ... and feel free to add it to your answer :)